# onmouseover and onmouseout event being triggered on page load not on events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
var statusList = document.createElement('ul'); //I am populating this list elsewhere
statusList.style.display = 'none';
var statusSpan = document.createElement('span');
statusSpan.onmouseover = mapControlHover(statusList);
statusSpan.onmouseout = mapControlNoHover(statusList);

function mapControlHover(element) {
  element.style.display = 'block';
}

function mapControlNoHover(element) {
  element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Both of the events are firing on page load (which they should not do). Neither are being fired `onmouseover` or `onmouseout`.

Please no jQuery in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is because you are invoking the event

```
statusSpan.onmouseover = mapControlHover(statusList);
```

You should just pass-in the event handler function reference.

```
statusSpan.onmouseover = mapControlHover
```

and

```
function mapControlHover() {
  statusList.style.display = 'block'; //access statusList directly here.
}
```

You can also use [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), see for support and polyfill for IE < 9

```
 statusSpan.onmouseover = mapControlHover.bind(statusSpan, statusList);
```

and access

```
function mapControlHover(element) {
  element.style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

Comment: @dan_vitch, Welcome. You would need to add the script for support below IE9. Which is mentioned in the MDN document.